# How to use a PHP function to delete data?

Tags: php, function, post

I have some data that I want to delete and I want to use a function to do that:

```
<input class="delete_challenge" type="submit" name="delete" value="" />
<input class="delete_defence" type="submit" name="delete" value="" />
```

```
$set = new fns_delete();
$delete_challenge = $set->challenge();
$delete_defence = $set->defence();
```

How do I use those buttons to call those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons will need to have different names:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete_challenge" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="delete_defence" value="" />
```

...

```
$set = new fns_delete;
if (isset($_POST['delete_challenge'])) {
   $delete_challenge = $set->challenge();
}
if (isset($_POST['delete_defence'])) {
   $delete_defence = $set->defence();
}
```

Be careful about giving users the ability to delete anything, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a form on an HTML page using an `input type="submit"` button, PHP will contain the name-value pair of the submit button in the POST or GET parameters.  So, the page that receives the submit needs to check for the presence of that value and do the action you want, whatever that is:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
<input class="delete_challenge" type="submit" name="delete_challenge" value="" />
<input class="delete_defence" type="submit" name="delete_defence" value="" />
</form>
```

Clicking the `delete_challenge` button will produce the following POST array:

```
$_POST = array(
    'delete_challenge' => ''
);
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST('delete_challenge'))) {
    // Do action
} else if (isset($_POST('delete_defence'))) {
    // Do action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways of doing this.

1) You can make the buttons do an ajax call to a php page doing the delete.

2) Get or Post from a form to a page where your delete functionality is triggered. (this could be the same page)

Example option 2:

Example form

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input class="delete_challenge" type="submit" name="delete" value="" />
  <input class="delete_defence" type="submit" name="delete" value="" />
</form>
```

Example php

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  $set = new fns_delete();
  $delete_challenge = $set->challenge();
  $delete_defence = $set->defence();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a couple of ways.

Use Ajax ( jquery would be easier ) to make a call to a php script and delete ( from database I suppose ? )

make the name of each button unique :
delete_challenge
delete_defence

PHP :

```
$set = new fns_delete();


if( $_POST['delete_challenge'] )
   $delete_challenge = $set->challenge();
else if ( $_POST['defence'] )
  $delete_defence = $set->defence();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you seam to miss the idea of server side versus client side scripting.

The code you wrote here is written in HTML.

PHP code such as the following, is not actually sent to the user.
    $set = new fns_delete();
    $delete_challenge = $set->challenge();
    $delete_defence = $set->defence();

All PHP can do, is print out HTML, which is then sent to the user.
What I would recommend you to do is read a bit about web development. A book that started me off was PHP and mysql for dummies. http://www.bol.com/nl/s/boeken/zoekresultaten/Ntt/php+and+mysql+for+dummies/search/true/searchType/qck/N/8299/Ntk/books_all/index.html

But I'll give you some basic information which may get you started. When a user requests a page using his web browser (the client), the server searhes for the requested file. When the server notices that the requested file, it will start to execute it. When it starts to do so, it will send anything contained in the file directly to the client, so a PHP file with the folllowing content

```
<html>
<body>
  <ul>
   <li>item 1</li>
   </li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

will look like this to the user

- item 1
- item 2

If you want the server to actually execute what's in the file, you need to use a starting PHP tag:

and an ending PHP tag
    ?>

so the same output as above can be generated by putting the following content in your file

```
<?php
echo "<html>
      <body>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
      </ul>
      </body>
      </html>";
?>
```

You can also combine the two to do some more interesting stuff such as the following content

```
<hr>
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
function add($num1,$num2){
    return $num1+$num2;
}
?>
Let's see what 1 + 2 equals<br>
<?php
echo "<hr>".add($a,$b);
?>
```

This will look like this when the browser receives it:

---

### let's see  what 1+2 equals

3

but what's actually happening here?
First, the server encounters

---

The server is in what we call HTML mode, it will send any output directly to the client. On the second line however, we have our PHP starting tat ()
Now, we are back in HTML mode, so the phrase 'let's see what 1+2 equals' is sent directly to the client. And then it's time to go back into PHP mode. Where we echo (print) nou another horizontal rule, concatinated with the output of the add function, given the values of $a and $b.

I hope that helps.